# Unable to mount ext4 file system, it says mount: unknown filesystem type 'ext4dev'?

Tags: mount, filesystem, ext4

I am trying to mount an ext4 file system in Ubuntu terminal, but I get the error message

```
mount: unknown filesystem type ext4dev
```

---

```
$ lsblk -f /dev/sdb1

NAME FSTYPE  LABEL     
sdb1 ext4dev ext4
```

The hard drive is working fine.

I don't understand why `FSTYPE` is `ext4dev`. it should be `ext4`, right?

The following is result from cat `/proc/filesystems`. What should I do to make my system read `ext4dev` hard drive. thanks

```
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   ramfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   cpuset
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cgroup2
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   configfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   tracefs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   pipefs
nodev   rpc_pipefs
nodev   devpts
        ext3
        ext2
        ext4
        vfat
        msdos
nodev   nfs
nodev   nfs4
nodev   autofs
        f2fs
nodev   mqueue
        fuseblk
nodev   fuse
nodev   fusectl
```

Comment: Where does this /dev/sdb1 come from? Has it been formatted on another system?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be `ext4`, not `ext4dev`. See the types of filesystems your system supports via `cat /proc/filesystems`.